# Offloading Computation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, implementation, python-3.8

**Background:**

For the purpose of processing an image file that has been processed into a sample by sample covariance matrix that is 65,000 by 65,000 in dimensions taking  32 GB of storage space. If each row (or each column) were to be loaded and offloaded from this matrix (e.g. 1 row by 65,000 columns for loading and offloading row by row) then most computers should be able to handle this processing requirement.

I have looked into a possible example of this algorithm being implemented, but with no luck. If anyone has seen an example please link it and I will accept that solution.

**Question:**

How can I alter my example code to do this row by row loading and offloading implementation for this processing algorithm?

**Example Code in python v3.8.5 64-bit:**

```html
file_name = file_to_be_edited.filetype
new_file_name = "new_" + file_name

input = r"C:\Users\user_name\project_folder" + "\\" + file_name

output = r"C:\Users\user_name\project_folder" + "\\" + new_file_name

input_file = open(input, "r")
output_file = open(output, "w")

for input_row in input_file:
  for character in range(0, len(input_row)):
    output_file.write(input_row[character])

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: principal component analysis (pca) and linear discriminant analysis (lda)

Comment: I can approximate the 65k by 65k sample by sample matrix by using the small 12 by 12 feature by feature covariance matrix and only consider the most significant eigen value principal components. But the point is I want to know how to optimally load and offload large data sets in the way I described for other implementations.